# I am not able to sync any projects from udacity in Android Studio.I am getting the following error everytime

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to build my Android project, but every time I try to I get this error:

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971. Searched
>   in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
>       file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
>       file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :app

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Provide some minimal explanation, not only the error dump. How your config looks like, steps to get to that point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, i have just changed google() position inside build.gradle like this :

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing out `google()` on your buildscript and allprojects
Just add the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() 
        // Your other repositories
    }
 }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        // Your other repositories
    }
}
```

Then rebuild your project.

Comment: @KavanaMk if it fixed your issue, please mark this answer as the correct one so it can help others ;)